# JavaScript for Mega Menu Loading Slowly

Tags: javascript, jquery

On our Magento Website we have a mega-menu which appears when the mouse hovers over a parent `li` element in the menu.

However, if you hover over the menu immediately as the page loads, the mega menu does not appear properly.

It's much worse if the user has a poor internet connection.

After checking the chrome inspector I see this is because the class `over` is not added to the parent `li`.  If you wait a second or two and move the mouse out & back over the parent `li` element the `over` class is added and the `display` css property of the mega menu is changed to `block`.

I've found the javascript adding the `over` class, it's part of the theme that we are using script.js.

```
//  CODE OMMITED FOR BREVITY
jQuery(window).load(function() {

    //  CODE OMMITED FOR BREVITY

    if(jQuery('#nav-wide').length){
        jQuery('#nav-wide li.level-top').mouseenter(function(){
            jQuery(this).addClass('over');
            if(mobileDevice == true){
                document.addEventListener('touchstart', wideMenuListener, false);
            }
        });
        jQuery('#nav-wide li.level-top').mouseleave(function(){
            jQuery(this).removeClass('over');
        });

        //  CODE OMMITED FOR BREVITY
    }

    //  CODE OMMITED FOR BREVITY

});
```

Any idea why this javascript would take so long to load?  Or how I could improve it?

Comment: without answering you why it takes so long to load... you can definitely put in a semi transparent screen overlay that shows a loading gif. Hide it after the js has been fully loaded.

Comment: I agree with @Ji_in_coding  ---  Most Magento stores load slowly anyway unless you do some serious code/server optimization.  Best bet is a "loading" overlay until the site is fully loaded.  --  The "reasons" Magento loads slowly are numerous.  I'd venture to say it's not "just" the JS that's loading slowly, rather the server is responding slowly due to the huge draw Magento puts on it ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've figured this out.

The theme is adding the `over` class within the `jQuery(window).load(function(){});` which loads when everything on the page has loaded i.e. when all images, objects & frames have loaded.  And we are using facebook widget *(frame)* on most pages.

The `jQuery(document).ready(function(){});` function loads when just the HTML Document is ready, which would be much sooner, almost a second in our case.

So I simply moved theme's mouseover event listener within to the `jQuery(document).ready()` function